# advice on building php based file manager

Tags: php

I am trying to build a php based file management system, but am having a few problems, basically I have found a script but it has problems reading directory names with spaces in them, here is the script :

```
<?php
global $dir_path;
if (isset($_GET["directory"])) {
$dir_path = $_GET["directory"];
//echo $dir_path;
}
else {
$dir_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/";
     }

$directories = scandir($dir_path);

foreach($directories as $entry) {
if (is_dir($dir_path . "/" . $entry) && !in_array($entry, array('.','..'))) {
    echo "<a href=?directory=" . $dir_path . "" . $entry . "/" . "><li>" . $entry . "</li></a>";


 }
else {}
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look for a better script to BORROW or maybe if all else fails write one yourself

Comment: It would be useful if you gave a bit more DETAIL as _it has problems reading directory names with spaces in them_ does not really describe the **actual** problem you are having

Comment: ok, if I access a directory called "directorya" I can see the sub-directories beneath it, however if i try to access a directory called "directory a", no sub-directories are listed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember, on Unix like systems directories with spaces in are a bit of a pain. You have to wrap then in quotes

Comment: ok, will try again, thank you for your time.